# How could I use the select statement on feature from a subquery ? (Postgree)

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm training for an interview and trying to solve a query, I would like to find for each city who is the client who spent the most. I got the good result the max spent by city but I get an error when I'm trying to retrieve the name and lastname of my customer who spent this amount. Is there an efficient way to do it ? Thank you!

```
select max(total_payment),X.city, X.firstname, X.lastname
from (
select sum(amount) as total_payment, c.customer_id, cit.city_id, cit.city as city, c.first_name as firstname, c.last_name as lastname
from payment p
inner join customer as c on p.customer_id=c.customer_id
inner join address as ad on c.address_id=ad.address_id
inner join city as cit on ad.city_id=cit.city_id
group by c.customer_id, cit.city_id
order by city
) as X
group by X.city
```

Target result column:
The name and last name of the customer who spent the most for each city.

120,Paris,Nicolas, Dupont

130, Madrid, Raul, Garcia

70, London,Dave, Goldman

Comment: Why select max(total_payment),X.city, X.firstname, X.lastname, but GROUP BY is only by X.city

Comment: Hi, it was because I just need the one who spent the most by city

Comment: OK. But then you need only select max(total_payment),X.city from(...)group by X.city

Comment: I would like the name of the one one who spent the most also

Comment: and if you have two? It would be better if you provide some sample data and desired output, because now it looks like you need some window-calculation

Comment: I would like for each city the customer(s) who spent the most if there are two it's fine, thank you I just add an output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want window functions:

```
select cc.*
from (select sum(p.amount) as total_payment, c.customer_id, cit.city_id, 
             cit.city as city, c.first_name as firstname, c.last_name as lastname,
             row_number() over (partition by cit.city order by sum(p.amount) desc) as seqnum
      from payment p join
           customer c
           on p.customer_id = c.customer_id join
           address ad
           on c.address_id = ad.address_id join
           city cit
           on ad.city_id = cit.city_id
      group by c.customer_id, cit.city_id
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that your query has two errors that should fail any interview:

1. You are using `ORDER BY` in a subquery.  According to the standard and most databases, `ORDER BY` is either not allowed or ignored.
2. In your outer query, the `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent with the unaggregated `SELECT` columns.  Once again, this violates the standard and most databases return a syntax error.

Comment: I have still so much to learn, thank you very much !

Comment: Sure I just did.